# AWS Kinesis Data Stream, is it possible for a parition key to belong to multiple shards?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

I'm new to Kinesis Data Streams and I'd like to know if the Kinesis Data Streams behavior is similar to the DynamoDB Streams behavior 
In DDB Streams, A partition key can only belong to 1 shard whereas 1 shard can hold multiple keys.

Is the same true for Kinesis Data Streams as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, shards are how streams scale. The partition key is used to associate the data record to a specific shard https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/key-concepts.html#partition-key